# Is implementation of Iterator for a specific collection in java is an example of Adapter design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, iterator, adapter

Is implementation of Iterator for a specific collection is an example of Adapter design pattern ?

For example:- 
iterator implementation of ArrayList wraps ArrayList adaptee, while iterator implementation of HashSet wraps HashSet adaptee.

Comment: Not really, because there isn't an underlyuing interface being adapted. It's just an example of an implementation.

Comment: Have you found below answers helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because all collection implementations in `Java` should extend `java.util.Collection` interface which has [iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator--) method. And there is no need to create adapter for collection to get iterator for it.

But we need to create adapter for other classes which do not implement `java.util.Collection` or `java.lang.Iterable`. For example, for well known `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair` class. Below example shows how to create adapter which allow to iterate over it properties like over collection:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class DesignPatterns {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pair<String, String> pair = new ImmutablePair("A", "B");
        for (String item : new PairIterableAdapter<>(pair)) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}

class PairIterableAdapter<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    private final Pair<T, T> pair;

    public PairIterableAdapter(Pair<T, T> pair) {
        this.pair = pair;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<>() {
            private int counter = 2;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return counter-- > 0;
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                switch (counter) {
                    case 1:
                        return pair.getLeft();
                    case 0:
                        return pair.getRight();
                    default:
                        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("No more elements!");
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
A
B
```

For collections we do not need to do that because theirs implementation already have `iterator()` method.

See also:

- [Adapter](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter)
- [Iterator](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/iterator)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting perspective!

In general, both `Adapter` and `Iterator` patterns are trying to solve different problems. Former is used to make existing incompatible entities (classes) work with each other without modifying them whereas,
the latter helps in sequentially accessing the elements of some aggregated entity (List or Collection) without the need to understand the underlying logic.

Coming back to your question,

> Is implementation of Iterator for a specific collection is an example
>   of Adapter design pattern ?

Not really.

The need for Adapter pattern arises when there already exist two incompatible classes and you are trying to introduce an Adapter to make the communication possible between the two classes. But in the case of Iterator pattern, we already have the `Iterator` interface defined. So it is the opposite. Any new class, wanting to interact with the `Collection` iterator, has to define itself in such a way that it can understand the Iterator interface. Besides, `iterator` limits the functionality to accessing elements of the underlying Collection whereas `Adapter` enables the communication between two classes.

Hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

No, both patterns rely on interfaces and [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)), particularly [information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding), but, as Girish and user207421 point out, they have different concerns:

- The Adapter pattern resolves differing interfaces, leveraging interfaces and information hiding
- The Iterator pattern provides a consistent interface to iterate arbitrary structures, also relying on interfaces and information hiding

Most patterns leverage one or more OOP fundamentals which is likely why you'd confuse them / find overlap, but it's their *concerns* which differentiate them.